# Can statistics be used to measure which model is the most accurate

Tags: model-selection

I found three websites which lists the times of sunrises and sunsets in the place where I live. But as those times differ occasionally some minutes, I would like to know if there is a method to find out which one is the most correct prediction. I heard that statistics provides some methods to compare models but on the other hand, I guess I have to measure the goodness of times to some formula before I can say how much the error is.

So, if someone asks for a statistician how to measure which model predicts most accurately sunset and sunrise times, what kind of test he or she would use to measure the goodness?

Comment: Are you able to measure or find the actual sunrise/sunset times with some degree of accuracy after they have occurred to test the predictions against some known/true values?  Also, is there a general agreed upon definition of sunset/sunrise that would disallow disagreeing estimates?  I'm not an expert in the field, but I would expect that the estimates are based off a mathematical model with little variance other than your physical viewing location.

Comment: I haven't found any database where are listed times that have occurred in the history. I'm sure there are formulae to estimate the times in astronomy books but I haven't any of those books. I don't know how physicists define the sunset/rise times or are there many definitions.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that all the estimates could be correct.  Perhaps they are estimating different things.  For instance, perhaps Method 1 is accurately estimating the sunset/sunrise time at location X.  Method 2 is accurately estimating the sunset/sunrise time at nearby location Y, a few miles away.  Without something to compare the estimates to, it is difficult to say which is more accurate, since you do not have a target to aim  at.